# Node-js: Processing multiple files vs processing a big file using line offset

Tags: node.js, file, stream

I'm retrieving a considerable amount of data from a NoSQL database limited by a given value (for simplicity, let's say 2 rows) and saving to a file so I could later process this data properly.

This database returns each table result in groups of rows. For instance, if my data had 3 groups and I used limit 2, I would get this result for the first query.

```
// Group 1
2020-03-09,A,1
2020-03-09,B,6
// Group 2
2020-03-09,A,2
2020-03-10,A,3
// Group 3
2020-03-10,A,4
2020-03-11,A,5
```

While I keep getting the data from the database by using limits + offsets, I will write a temporary file with these jumps between groups until it ends up reading all the data. Note the dates are ordered between groups, and the same group may have the same date in different lines.

```
// Group 1 (lines 1-2)
// Group 2 (lines 3-4)
// Group 3 (lines 5-6)
// Group 1 (lines 7-8)
// Group 2 (lines 9-10)
// Group 3 (lines 11-12)
```

For the parsing phase, I want to write a final processed file with the date as the primary key in order, using the following format:

```
date, group1_A, group1_B, group2_A, group3_A
2020-03-09, 1, 6, 2, (null)
2020-03-10, (null), (null), 3, 4
2020-03-11, (null), (null), (null), 5
```

Since I know the offsets and which lines I should read for the parsing phase, assuming all the groups will have the same number of lines until the end, I need to go to each group, line by line, and compare the dates between groups to insert data in date order in a new file, like a join operation.

I figured I could do this by using multiple files (one file per group) and multiple readstreams, but the number of groups could be more than 1000 and I'm afraid that I could have a high overhead due to opening/processing multiple files. So I thought it would be better to use a single file and point to different lines of the file by using an offset so I could make these comparisons between groups. However, I don't know if the latter approach is even possible in node.js (read a given line in a file without processing it entirely).

If someone could give me guidance here, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Is there a reason for having the intermediary file and not go straight for the final file? Maybe there is something I am missing. As I understand you are getting data from your database in ascending order by date, and you want to write your final file by dates in ascending order. In that case I would expect that you could keep on reading from the DB and placing the values in an in-memory-object until you reach a DB entry with a new date, then write the object as a line to the file and rinse and repeat.

Comment: I thought of using a temporary file because of two reasons: there's a limit I can get from the database into memory and the dates may also repeat for the same group, so there is no guarantee that the last date Y in the limited group X is the last date for Y in general. So say if I start comparing the dates for group 1,2,3 and find a minimum date, the next step would be to go over group 1's next line and find the minimum again. If I focus on getting the data from the database to a local file, and then process line by line, I believe I can get the results without reaching the heap limit.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you could e.g. get data like this:
`// Group 1
2020-03-09,A,1
2020-03-09,B,6
// Group 2
2020-03-09,A,2
2020-03-10,A,3
// Group 3
2020-03-10,A,4
2020-03-11,A,5
// Group 1
2020-03-09,C,1
2020-03-09,D,6`

Comment: Comment formatting is terrible - sorry. I am trying understand whether dates are in fact ordered between groups or not.